# How to perform arithmetic operation on two seperate dataframes in Apache Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes as follows which have only one row and one column each. Both holds two different numeric values.

How do I perform or achieve division or other arithmetic operation on those two dataframe values?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have dataframes as

```
scala> df1.show(false)
+------+
|value1|
+------+
|2     |
+------+

scala> df2.show(false)
+------+
|value2|
+------+
|2     |
+------+
```

You can get the value by doing the following

```
scala> df1.take(1)(0)(0)
res3: Any = 2
```

But the dataType is `Any`, type casting is needed before we do arithmetic operations as

```
scala> df1.take(1)(0)(0).asInstanceOf[Int]*df2.take(1)(0)(0).asInstanceOf[Int]
res8: Int = 4
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help. You helped me get success.

Comment: I am glad that it helped you :) @RahulMukherjee. you can accept the answer and upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

First, if these DataFrames contain a *single* record each - any further use of Spark would likely be wasteful (Spark is intended for large data sets, small ones would be processed faster locally). So, you can simply collect these one-record values using `first()` an go on from there:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df1 = Seq(2.0).toDF("col1")
val df2 = Seq(3.5).toDF("col2")

val v1: Double = df1.first().getAs[Double](0)
val v2: Double = df2.first().getAs[Double](0)

val sum = v1 + v2
```

If, for some reason, you do want to use DataFrames all the way, you can use `crossJoin` to join the records together and then apply any arithmetic operation:

```
import spark.implicits._

val df1 = Seq(2.0).toDF("col1")
val df2 = Seq(3.5).toDF("col2")

df1.crossJoin(df2)
  .select($"col1" + $"col2" as "sum")
  .show() 

// +---+
// |sum|
// +---+
// |5.5|
// +---+
```